# Postgresql, how to query the database based on a certain condition?

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to write a postgresql statement that would allow me to execute a certain query only if a condition is satisfied:

```
select SUM("TotalBookings") AS Availability,
from (select count (*) as "TotalBookings" 
from bookings 
where hotel_id=2 and ('2023-02-10') between symmetric check_in_date and check_out_date
union all 
select -count (*) as "TotalRooms" 
from hotels 
inner join rooms on rooms.hotel_id = hotels.hotel_id 
where hotels.hotel_id=2 ) Availability;



case
   when Availability >= 1 
           then select * 
           from hotels 
           where hotel_id=2 
   end
```

I basically would like to show my hotels only when the sum is greater than one.

Below the error returned:

syntax error at or near "from"

Any ideas on whether mine is only a syntax error or if my logic is wrong as well ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: , from on the first and second line, that's not correct.

Comment: I removed the from and it now throws a syntax error at or near "select"

Comment: Because there is also a ; in the middle of your piece of SQL. Advice: Use a proper IDE for writing SQL, saves you a lot of time